# Regular Expression for number.(space), objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

I have an NSArray of lines (objective-c iphone), and I'm trying to find the line which starts with a number, followed by a dot and a space, but can have any number of spaces (including none) before it, and have any text following it eg:

```
    1. random text
           2. text random
3.
```

what regular expression would I use to get this? (I'm trying to learn it, and I needed the above expression anyway, so I thought I'd use it as an example)

Comment: python is spot on for regular expression

Comment: Oops, sorry. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C#:

```
@"^ *[0-9]+\. "
```

It doesn't check for the presence of something after the `.`, so this is legal:

```
1.(space)
```

If you delete the `@` and escape the `\` it should work with other languages (it is pretty "down-to-earth" as RegExpes go)

Comment: thank you, this works except if there is text after the number, which there can be.

Comment: "^ *[0-9]+\. .\*" if your RegExp doesn't catch substrings... But it's strange, it isn't anchored to the end.

Comment: thank you that works great, and thanks for the fast answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest (Perl-compatible regexp):

```
^\s*\d+\.\s
```

At the beginning of a line:

- Any number (0-n) of spaces
- One or more digits
- A dot
- A space

Comment: Depending on the language, you are catching tabs, nbsp... with the \s, and with the \d you are catching non-standard numbers (numbers that aren't [0-9]). I don't know if this is "wanted" by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
^\s*\d+\.
```

But it depends on the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\s*[0-9]+\.\s+/
```

would be my guess providing you don't have any space before the number

Comment: there may or may not be a space.

Comment: Amended my example to allow for spaces

Comment: @Mikel's use of \d is much cleaner than [0-9] so use it if it's available in the flavour of regex that you use